# Springboot Postgresql The column name INDEX_NAME was not found in this resultset

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pgadmin

I have a springboot project and this project works on other computers. I tried it on 2 different computers and it works but it does not work on my computer. It gives an error and it says "The column name INDEX_NAME was not found in this resultset". I guess it cannot reach the indexes of the database tables. I use postgresql and I uninstalled it and I reinstalled. I even formatted my computer and reinstalled it. Why doesn't it just work on my computer?

Error message is :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JaversFromStarter' defined in class path resource [org/javers/spring/boot/sql/JaversSqlAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.polyjdbc.core.exception.SchemaInspectionException: [INDEX_LOOKUP_ERROR] Failed to obtain relation index list when looking for indexes for relation jv_global_id
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.provera.taskmanapi.TaskmanapiApplication.main(TaskmanapiApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.polyjdbc.core.exception.SchemaInspectionException: [INDEX_LOOKUP_ERROR] Failed to obtain relation index list when looking for indexes for relation jv_global_id
    at org.polyjdbc.core.schema.SchemaInspectorImpl.indexExists(SchemaInspectorImpl.java:115) ~[polyjdbc-0.7.6.jar:na]
    at org.javers.repository.sql.schema.JaversSchemaManager.addIndex(JaversSchemaManager.java:336) ~[javers-persistence-sql-6.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.javers.repository.sql.schema.JaversSchemaManager.addDbIndexOnOwnerId(JaversSchemaManager.java:100) ~[javers-persistence-sql-6.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.javers.repository.sql.schema.JaversSchemaManager.ensureSchema(JaversSchemaManager.java:59) ~[javers-persistence-sql-6.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.javers.repository.sql.JaversSqlRepository.ensureSchema(JaversSqlRepository.java:186) ~[javers-persistence-sql-6.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalJpaDecorator$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(JaversTransactionalJpaDecorator.java:64) ~[javers-spring-jpa-6.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:36) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalJpaDecorator.ensureSchema(JaversTransactionalJpaDecorator.java:61) ~[javers-spring-jpa-6.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalJpaDecorator.afterPropertiesSet(JaversTransactionalJpaDecorator.java:55) ~[javers-spring-jpa-6.6.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bu ResultSet içinde INDEX_NAME sütun adı bulunamadı.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2957) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getString(PgResultSet.java:2814) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getString(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.polyjdbc.core.schema.SchemaInspectorImpl.indexExists(SchemaInspectorImpl.java:107) ~[polyjdbc-0.7.6.jar:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

Cause of the problem is your computer language. I guess, you use the computer as Turkish language. You should change as English

I had same problem. I fixed this way

Answer (score 0):

Your index is not created properly, it should include the foreign key as well, and also the index should have unique keys.

Comment: I am using the database as code first. Spring boot can create tables and indexes on other computers but same codes give an error on my computer. So should I create the database table myself?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that the Java JDBC driver has difficulty processing the contents of the ResultSet object in accordance with Turkish localization settings. In this case, a column name within the ResultSet is misinterpreted and processed incorrectly, resulting in the error.

If you add the following environment to your .bashrc/.zshrc file, the problem will be fixed.

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US"
```